# Blazor selected Row parameter transfer

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor

I have created a table here and would like to transfer the selected parameter to the component in the header area.

[image]

**UserList.razor**

```
<RadzenDataGrid Data="@usermodel"
                TItem="Userlistmodel"
                @bind-Value="@selectedUser"
                RowSelect=@RowSelect>
<Columns>
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="PNRUID" Title="PNRUID" Width="120px" />
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="PNR" Title="PNR" Width="120px" />
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="Nachname" Title="Nachname" Width="170px" />
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="Vorname" Title="Vorname" Width="170px" />
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="Geburtsdatum" Title="Geburtsdatum" /></Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

 <RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom:20px">
     User:
     <b>@selectedUser.FirstOrDefault()?.Nachname</b>
 </RadzenCard>

@code{

public IList<Userlistmodel>? selectedUser { get; set; }

void RowSelect( Userlistmodel userlistmodel )
{
    Console.WriteLine( userlistmodel.Nachname );
}
}
```

I tried the following to transfer the data **(Nachname)** in the header area. Something is still missing. A component **(UserInfo.razor)** is implemented in the header area.

**UserInfo.razor**

```
@using LMERP.AppAdmin.Shared.Models.UserMgmt

<div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
    <h3>Header area</h3>
    <div class="col-1">
        <RadzenIcon Icon="account_box" Class="icon-s icon-outline icon-header-1 hidden-1 mt-header" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 pl-2">
        <div class="text div-header-1 hidden-2">
            <b>User:</b>
            @if ( selectedUser?.Any() == true )
            {
                foreach ( var role in selectedUser )
                {
                    <p class="mb-0">@role.Nachname</p>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <p class="mb-0">Select Name</p>
            }
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Nachname { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IList<Userlistmodel>? selectedUser { get; set; }

}
```

It also didn't work with CascadingValue.

Comment: Is the `UserList` component used inside the `UserInfo.razor`? Or you have a parent component that contains both `UserList` and `UserInfo`?

Comment: ** UserList.razor ** is a page, and in MainLayout.razor the ** UserInfo.rozor** 
 component is integrated as ** <UserInfo/>** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by implementing an in-memory state container service like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly#in-memory-state-container-service).

Create a `StateContainer` class.

```
public class StateContainer
{
    private Userlistmodel? _selectedUser;

    public Userlistmodel? SelectedUser
    {
        get => _selectedUser;
        set
        {
            _selectedUser = value;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
    }

    public event Action? OnChange;

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

Register as singleton service in `Program.cs` (or scoped for Blazor server-side)

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<StateContainer>();
```

Inside `UserList.razor`:

```
@inject StateContainer State

<RadzenDataGrid Data="@usermodel"
                TItem="Userlistmodel"
                @bind-Value="@selectedUser"
                RowSelect=@RowSelect>
<Columns>
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="PNRUID" Title="PNRUID" Width="120px" />
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="PNR" Title="PNR" Width="120px" />
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="Nachname" Title="Nachname" Width="170px" />
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="Vorname" Title="Vorname" Width="170px" />
 <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Userlistmodel" Property="Geburtsdatum" Title="Geburtsdatum" /></Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

 <RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom:20px">
     User:
     <b>@selectedUser.FirstOrDefault()?.Nachname</b>
 </RadzenCard>

@code{

    public IList<Userlistmodel>? selectedUser { get; set; }

    void RowSelect( Userlistmodel userlistmodel )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( userlistmodel.Nachname );
        State.SelectedUser = userlistmodel;
    }
}
```

and inside `UserInfo.razor`

```
@implements IDisposable
@inject StateContainer State

@if (State.SelectedUser != null)
{
    <p>@State.SelectedUser.Nachname</p>
}

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        StateContainer.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```